# How to serialize an object to/from a single string value

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

If I have a basic class, lets call it ValidationType and it has a string property Value, how would I make it so that it serializes using System.Text.Json too from that string value?

IE

```
//I want the below object to serialize/deserialize to/from the string "Error"
var validationType = new ValidationType() {Value = "Error"};
var str = JsonSerializer.Serialize(validationType) // Would give "Error"
var deserialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ValidationType>(str) // Would give back the original object assigned to var validationType
```

Comment: Just asking for better understanding, you want to serialize with `"Error"` and deserialize from `"Error"` to your `ValidationType`?

Comment: I want `new ValidationType() {Value = "Error"}` to serialize to "Error" and I want "Error" to deserialize back to `new ValidationType() {Value = "Error"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own [converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0) to convert your `ValidationType` object to a string and vice-versa. The converter can look like this:

```
public class ValidationTypeConverter : JsonConverter<ValidationType>
{
    public override ValidationType Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        string str = reader.GetString();
        return new ValidationType
        {
            Value = str
        };
    }
    
    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        ValidationType obj,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(obj.Value);
    }
}
```

Add this converter to your `JsonSerializerOptions` instance and use it in your `Serialize()` and `Deserialize()` calls.

```
var validationType = new ValidationType()
{
    Value = "Error"
};

JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions ();
options.Converters.Add(new ValidationTypeConverter());
var str = JsonSerializer.Serialize(validationType, options);
Console.WriteLine(str);
var deserialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ValidationType>(str, options);
Console.WriteLine(deserialized.Value);
```

This will generate the following output:

```
"Error"
Error
```

Comment: @NathanKamenar You might want to check https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-it-required-to-provide-comments-feedback-for-downvotes-and-why-are-pr

Answer (score 0):

Well lets make it step by step

```
var str = JsonSerializer.Serialize(validationType.Value);
```

and `str` is equal this: `Error`

When you deserialize it you need more code.

```
var deserialized = MyDeserialize(str);
```

And the `MyDeserialize` method is:

```
    public ValidationType MyDeserialize(string str)
    {
        return new ValidationType { Value = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string>(str)};
    }
```

deserialized is equal this : `object ValidationType` and its value is `Error`

Comment: This sort of solves it but not in the way I need. I am not always the one directly serializing the model. Sometimes it gets serialized automatically to travel across the wire from a user edit form for example. I am trying to get it so that the exact 3 line scenario in my original post would work meaning that serializing an instance of ValidationType class gives back the string Value and vice versa.